# How to delete a Mysql-Statement with a specific ID in a form?

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I want to delete a entry in a database. So I made a (working!) table with the entries shown. So I want to delete the one entry, which I push a button "delete".
I thought I have to make a second php-file, but I don't know how to catch the ID of the selected entry. Here is my code of the first data:

```
while ($datensatz = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
        $id = $datensatz['id'];
        echo "<form action='PHP/deleteditadmin.php'><tr>";
        echo "<input type='hidden' name='iid' value='$id' />";
        echo "<td name='id'>" . $id . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $datensatz['name'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $datensatz['server'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td><input type='submit' name='deleteadmin' value='L&ouml;schen' /></td>";
        echo "<td><input type='submit' name='editadmin' value='Edit' /></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
```

And here is the deleteditadmin.php

```
<?php
        $hostname = 'localhost';
        $dbname   = 'XX';
        $username = 'XX';
        $password = 'XX';
        $con = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or DIE('Connection to host isailed, perhaps the service is down!');
        mysqli_select_db($con, $dbname) or DIE('Database name is not available!');

        if($_POST['deleteadmin'])
        {
            $idwert = $_POST['$iid'];
            $remove= "DELETE FROM admins WHERE id='$idwert'";
            $removequery = mysqli_query($con, $remove);
        }

         mysqli_close($con);
         header("location:../adminlist.php");
?>
```

So, I need the second submit button for another function in the same php-file. I just want to delete only the one datarow in which I clicked the "delete" button. 
Thanks

Comment: Hm - as of now both of your button do delete the entry, right? What should happen on click of "Edit"? Maybe instead of submitting the form you want to open an edit form? So maybe a simple <a href"...?id=..."> might be better here?

Comment: There I must take my mind later how I could change the entries. But how could I delete the selected?

Comment: Ah. You check for $_POST['deleteadmin'] - change that to $_POST['iid']  and remove $ in $idwert = $_POST['iid'];

Comment: It looks like you already have the id in the form. Just check for `$_POST['iid']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
    if($_POST['deleteadmin'])
    {
        $idwert = $_POST['iid'];
        $remove= "DELETE FROM admins WHERE id='".$idwert."'";
        $removequery = mysqli_query($con, $remove);
    }
```

Comment: But isn't 'iid' even posted when push the "edit"-button?

Comment: Hm yes, that's right. So keep the `if` if you *know* that works. The part in error before was the access to your `iid` value and how you put it into the SQL.

Comment: Could I not check in the php-file which of the both buttons was pushed?

Comment: probably yes - but as it is you don't have any input fields to edit... I'd think you're good with a list from where you can delete or call edit - and then edit will show form to change something with it's own PHP script to do the changes.

Comment: What for a list do you mean? I'm a little bit new with PHP, so I don't know the best way to set this. If you want, I can give you a link to the page and there you can have a look what I wanna do

Comment: Yes, that would be fun. I was referring to your List of Datensatz - you have one form per table line there - but no input fields you would edit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97836/discussion-between-johnhsmith-and-jan).